# Mimic fonts and spacing of tufte-book class

Tags: fonts, spacing, tufte

I am writing a book using memoir class and I want to mimic fonts and spacing of tufte-book class.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Try `\input{tufte-common.def}`

Comment: Although I have voted for close I admit, it was too fast -- I am sorry about this. Therefore I have voted for reopen

Comment: Your Question was put *on hold* after an unusual short time. You can improve your question by explaining what exactly you mean by mimic the spacing. Spacing of what exactly?

Comment: It is consider good practice to show us an MWE of what you have so for (as mentioned above by Benedikt Bauer). You will probably have to get a bit more specific on what you mean by "mimic the spacing" of the `tufte-book` class, is it about margins (and margin notes)?

Comment: You can find the typeface, size, leading, and style information used in the Tufte-LaTeX classes on page 19 of the [Tufte-LaTeX documentation (PDF)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/sample-book.pdf). Chapters 3 and 4 of the [`memoir` documentation (PDF)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) explain how to set the font sizes and heading styles.

Comment: While there have been some helpful comments (I think), your question as it stands now, is very unclear and unspecific about what you want/need and have so far. Please make it more specific; otherwise your question may be closed as "unclear what you're asking".